# GLM in R: Difference between estimates from glmer-summary and from effects-package

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I set up a GLMM in R using `glmer()` from `lme4` package. I used effects package for calculating estimates and CIs for fixed effects. 
I'm new to GLMMs, so my question is how the estimates provided by the `effects` package are calculated and in which way they differ from log-means given in the `glmer`-summary?

For example if I run

```
Model = glmer(response ~ fixed1 + fixed2 + (1 | random), data=df, family = poisson)
```

summary(Model) returns the following:

```
              Estimate      Std. Error      z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     -0.1459        0.4863       -0.300        0.764
fixed1_level2    0.3044        0.4479        0.680        0.497
fixed2_level2    0.2298        0.3212        0.716        0.474
fixed2_level3    0.3576        0.3368        1.062        0.288
```

Whereas summary(allEffects(Model)) returns this:

```
fixed1 effect

fixed1_level1     fixed1_level2 
1.125860          1.526514 

fixed2 effect

fixed2_level1     fixed2_level2     fixed2_level3
1.115492          1.403738          1.594999
```

Comment: a small example would be helpful.  The `effects` package constructs linear combinations of parameter estimates from the `glmer()` fit that correspond to effects of interest ...

Comment: added example to my post

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this question is not specific to mixed models - it would be applicable to any *generalized* linear model.

The standard parameterization for models with categorical predictors in R (*treatment contrasts*) is that the intercept term gives the expected value for the first level of the factor on the "linear predictor" or "link" scale (the log scale in this case), while the second and subsequent terms give the differences (again on the log scale) between the expected values of the second, third, ... levels and the first level.  Thus (if the parameters are `b0`, `b1`, `b2`) the predicted value of the first level is `exp(b0)`, of the second is `exp(b0+b1)`, of the third is `exp(b0+b2)`.  Testing for your example:

```
> exp(-2.4858)
[1] 0.08325892
> exp(-2.4858+1.6187)
[1] 0.4201683
> exp(-2.4858+0.8966)
[1] 0.2040888
```

These match up to round-off error.

Comment: Your explanations helped a lot! But why there is only one Intercept-value in `summary` if I include several effects in a model? However, the `effects`-package returns different estimates for first level of each effect in this case.

Comment: can you edit your question to provide an example where there are several effects in a model? This is fairly straightforward but would be easier to explain with an example.

Comment: I added an proper example.